# Pandas data frame Concatenate and Sorting the Index

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a dataframe with one categorical column, I divided dataframe to do manipulation depending on category now want to merge the dataset,

```
index A   B   C   
 1    M   2.2 3.4 
 2    F   3.4 1.0
 3    M   3.0 2.1
  .
  .
  .
```

created two new dataframe

```
index A   B   C   
 1    M   2.2 3.4 
 3    M   3.0 2.1
      .
      .
      .



   index A   B   C   
     2   F   3.4 1.0
          .
          .
          .
```

I want to get the resultant output as:

```
index A   B   C    D
 1    M   2.2 3.4  2.8
 2    F   3.4 1.0  3.4
 3    M   3.0 2.1  2.05
      .
      .
      .
```

I tried to do merge and concat but not getting desired solution.

Comment: Maybe use [pandas concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) using the argument `axis = 1` for merging the columns, which should use your aligned columns and create the desired output.

Comment: Apart from pandas `concat`, append also can be used.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html has examples for merging dataframes.

Comment: and where did column D come from in your example?

Comment: @ DavidErickson D is calculated based on the group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list of dataframes and then concatenate all

```
import pandas as pd
frames = [df1, df2] # df1 and df2 are two dataframes
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

or you can simply use append

```
result = df1.append(df2)
```

A better way would be:

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df4], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html